# Cocoa: How to dismiss multiple modal window / Modal View Controllers at once?

Tags: macos, cocoa, modalviewcontroller, modal-window

I have a situation that one window present modal view controller and then user can tap to open new modal controller and it can go on. Each model controller have a button to dismiss and requirement is that it should come back to the first view controller which was presenting them.

For eg A presents B present C presents D. Now when user will press dismiss in D then it should come to A.

What is happening if I do this all view controller dismisses but Modal session stays there i.e app become unresponsive as if model window is still there.

Comment: How are you stopping each modal session?

Comment: I have a notification it will notify all controllers. Only Base controller ignore that and rest I do dismiss(self). I tried to close window also checking if it is not main window instance, But that too not working

Comment: I was asking how you are stopping each modal session - just dismissing/closing the window won't do that.